# Django/Python 'int' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, django

at my models.py i got a class named Post with and ImageField called postcover. I want to save every image in PNG format which is working fine so far but i have no idea how i could keep the actual image aspectio ratio after processing the image.

with the following solution i get the following error:

> 'int' object is not subscriptable

models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
...
postcover = fields.ImageField(
        verbose_name="Post Cover",
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        upload_to=get_file_path_user_uploads,
        validators=[default_image_size, default_image_file_extension]
    )
...
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(Post, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    if self.postcover:
        if os.path.exists(self.postcover.path):
            imageTemproary = Image.open(self.postcover)
            outputIoStream = BytesIO()
            baseheight = 500
            hpercent = (baseheight / float(self.postcover.size[1]))
            wsize = int((float(self.postcover.size[0]) * float(hpercent)))
            imageTemproaryResized = imageTemproary.resize((wsize, baseheight))
            imageTemproaryResized.save(outputIoStream, format='PNG')
            outputIoStream.seek(0)
            self.postcover = InMemoryUploadedFile(outputIoStream, 'ImageField',
                                                  "%s.png" % self.postcover.name.split('.')[0], 'image/png',
                                                  sys.getsizeof(outputIoStream), None)
    super(Post, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

full trace:

```
 Internal Server Error: /post/2/edit/
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
     response = get_response(request)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 126, in _get_response
     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 124, in _get_response
     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
   File "/app/app_Accounts/decorators.py", line 33, in _wrapped_view
     return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ratelimit/decorators.py", line 30, in _wrapped
     return fn(*args, **kw)
   File "/app/app/views.py", line 473, in post_edit
     post.save()
   File "/app/app/models.py", line 204, in save
     hpercent = (baseheight / float(self.postcover.size[1]))
 TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

Thanks for help in advance :)

Comment: Please include the full traceback of the exception; in the web view there is a 'text only' link for this.

Comment: And what is `self.postcover` here? Is it a file object? If so, then `.size` can't be an *image* size (tuple with width and height), perhaps you meant to use `imageTemproary.size` instead?

Comment: Just added the full trace

Comment: And yes it is a file object

Comment: Then `self.postcover.size` is not a tuple. That's the file size in bytes. Use `imageTemproary.size`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to treat the file size as a tuple with width and height. You want to use `imageTemproary.size` instead, not `self.postcover.size`:

```
hpercent = baseheight / imageTemproary.size[1]
wsize = int(imageTemproary.size[0] * hpercent)
```

I've simplified the code too, you are using Python 3, where `/` produces a float value even if the inputs are both integers (true division, not floor division).

You may want to correct the spelling of the image object variable (`imageTemporary`); personally I'd just use `image`.